# How to find the two strings that occurs most in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, max, find-occurrences

I'm trying to get the number of the two elements that are the most frequent in an array. For example, in the list `['aa','bb','cc','dd','bb','bb','cc','ff']` the number of the most frequent should be `3`(the number of times 'bb' appear in the array) and the second most frequent `2`(number of times 'cc' appear in the array).

I tried this:

```
max = 0
snd_max = 0
for i in x:
 aux=x.count(i)
 if aux > max
   snd_max=max
   max=aux

print(max, snd_max)
```

But I was in doubt if there is an easier way?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `collections.Counter`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
x = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','bb','bb','cc','ff']
counter = Counter(x)
print(counter.most_common(2))
```

```
[('bb', 3), ('cc', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','bb','bb','cc','ff']
b = list(dict.fromkeys(l))
a = [(l.count(x), x) for x in b]
a.sort(reverse=True)
a = a[:2]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use max(), it's simple.

```
lst = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','bb','bb','cc','ff']
print(max(set(lst), key=lst.count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas value_counts()

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Put the list into the dataframe, then use value counts.

That will give you a dataframe with each element and and how many times it appears, sorted by the most common on top.